# Modify CSS file using Math.Random();

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to have a background image changed using

> Math.floor((Math.random());

One of the line in my CSS file which is called within my HTML file is:

```
.slider { width: 990px;  height: 378px; position: relative;  background: url(images/slide-img.png) no-repeat 0 0;}
```

What I am looking to do is use the following statement to get a random number from 1 to 4 and display different background images based on the number retrieved randomly. So I decided to delete the above line from the CSS file and add the following code in my HTML file:

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random()*4)+1); // random number (no more than 4 or the array will be out of bounds)
if (randomNumber == 1) {
    document.write ('<style>.slider { width: 990px;  height: 378px; position: relative;  background: url(images/slide-img.png) no-repeat 0 0;}</style>');
}
if (randomNumber == 2) {
    document.write ('<style>.slider { width: 990px;  height: 378px; position: relative;  background: url(images/slide-img2.png) no-repeat 0 0;}</style>');
}
if (randomNumber == 3) {
    document.write ('<style>.slider { width: 990px;  height: 378px; position: relative;  background: url(images/slide-img3.png) no-repeat 0 0;}</style>');
}
if (randomNumber == 4) {
    document.write ('<style>.slider { width: 990px;  height: 378px; position: relative;  background: url(images/slide-img4.png) no-repeat 0 0;}</style>');
}
```

That produced a blank HTML page. I am trying to do this without creating four separate CSS file using the above method.

Comment: Why don't you just have styles named like "slider1", "slider2", etc. and then apply the class name based on the result of the `Math.random()` ?

Comment: You are overwriting the document, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.open?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fdocument.open

Comment: Where would I apply that? in the HTML file?

Comment: I figured that is what I was doing :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Jquery [fantastic]
take a demo LIVE in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/samuelbigas/TFVNn/)

html:

```
<div class="slider"></div>
```

css:

```
.slider {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    -webkit-background-size:100% 100%;
    -moz-background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border: 2px black solid;
}
```

JavaScrip:

```
$(function () {
    var url = "http://maispc.com/samuel/content/images/",
        imgArray = [url+"avatar.png",
                   url+"provider/blogger.png",
                   url+"provider/LinkedIn-32x32.png",
                   url+"provider/myspace.png",
                   url+"provider/instagram.png",
                   url+"provider/Twitter-32x32.png",
                   url+"provider/stackoverflow.png",
                   url+"provider/Facebook-32x32.png"],
        randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * imgArray.length)),
        baseUrl = "url('" + imgArray[randomNumber] + "')";

    $(".slider").css('background-image', baseUrl); })();
```

take a demo LIVE in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/samuelbigas/TFVNn/)

Comment: So remove the background URL completely from the .slider class and use the JavaScript to add it. Correct?

Comment: I tried adding your code and the Background image is missing now, please see here: http://www.interfaithmedical.com/Portal/index2.php (the random image works but there is an error now) I commented out the script and I do not see the error.

Comment: Actually NVM... The path to the background image was wrong!!! You helped me and I accepted your answer. Thank you.

Comment: I have updated the example here and in JSFiddle.. check it out.

Answer (score 3):

`document.write` will replace the current content. of the page by what you are writing.

Use: `document.getElementsByClassName('slider')` iterate through the elements and set the background image using `element.style.backgroundImage=...`

Comment: Something like what hackNightly mentioned?

Comment: Yes, basically that.... the only difference is that he posted a code example and I gave you the instructions on how to do it

Answer (score 1):

Since the only thing that's changing is the background image, I'd just apply the style using javascript. Something like

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random()*4)+1),
    sliders = document.getElementsByClassName('slider');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(sliders, function (elm) {
  elm.style.background = 'url(images/slide-img' + randomNumber + '.png)';
});
```

- this has not been tested

Comment: AFAIK `getElementsByClassName` returns a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)/[`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList) which does not inherit from the Array prototype (no `forEach` method). Better explained on [Why can't I use forEach or map on a NodeList?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#Why_can%27t_I_use_forEach_or_map_on_a_NodeList.3F)

Comment: Yes, though I'm not in a position to test it, that should get you on the right track.

Comment: I should have the CSS and then the script or the other way around listed on the page?

Comment: I was able to rectify the issue taking your code and Samual's and get it to work. Thanks.